# Dialogue and abbreviations

Tags: abbreviations

She asked, "Will you come sit at the VIP table with us?"

In dialogue should it be V.I.P.?

thanks

Comment: Dialogue is spoken, and therefore has no punctuation, so there's no difference. Either abbreviation would be pronounced /viyaypi/, with or without periods.

Comment: Arguably, it should be *V-I-P table* in dialogue, because the typical styling of written dialogue is to use single letters separated by dashes. However, you've picked an unfortunate example. [VIP](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/VIP) has become so common that it's now an actual noun in its own right—in the same way that *laser* is now a noun rather than just an acronym (although it, unlike *VIP*, has become lowercase). In this particular case, you would use *VIP*. But if it weren't a noun, or something else common, convention would make it, for example, *sit at the C-U-W-Q table.*

Comment: Note that my last comment was not about written English per se, but about the conventions around how to spell and punctuate dialogue versus narrative in literature. For example, numerals (aside from a few exceptions) are never used in dialogue. You would always write *one*, not *1*, and *oh* (or *zero*), not *0*. Those exceptions aside, only in narrative are numerals okay. You'd probably get more extensive advice at the [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) site, where such conventions of style are on topic—and a full answer could be given, rather than just these comments.